# How to detach subscrber from a subject in Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I am writing a program that need to attach/detach event handlers from event source dynamically.
This happens many times, and I don't want any message loss or duplication by attach/detach.

But it seems I am doing something wrong here to detach Combine subscribers.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

let a = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()
var b = a
    .buffer(size: .max, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .customError({ fatalError() }))
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
a.send("AAA")
b.cancel()
a.send("BBB")
b = a
    .buffer(size: .max, prefetch: .byRequest, whenFull: .customError({ fatalError() }))
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
a.send("CCC")
RunLoop.main.run()
```

This prints this.

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
CCC
```

`CCC` is duplicated and `BBB` is unexpected. It seesms cancelling `b` doesn't detach it from its source `a`. It seems I am doing these things completely wrong.

What is proper way to attach/detach subscribers from subject? In this case, I want to attach/detach `b` from `a` dynamically.

- Xcode 11 GM.

Comment: I don't think that you are doing anything wrong just too quickly. My guess is that the first pipeline hasn't disappeared when the second is created. You could prove that by adding some extra text to the two print statements. The documentation for cancel() doesn't say anything about when it will take effect. You could try assigning nil to b instead of calling cancel(). I think that you will need to define b as AnyCancellable? in that case.

Comment: @MichaelSalmon I agree on your guess. Immediate and dynamic attach/detach  ability (handling this situation correctly) is requirement for my program. If Combine is not designed to support this scenario, I just simply cannot rely on it.

Comment: I would try using nil before giving it up completely.

Comment: @MichaelSalmon I tried setting it to nil, and got same result. Thanks for cheering anyway.